# Problem with Customizing Footnotes witb babel-french

Tags: footnotes, babel, footmisc

I need to adjust a bit the French style of footnotes according to the wishes of my publisher : in the footnote, the number should be on the line, with no indentation (and flushed left). I need babel-french for a variety of reasons. I have tried several solutions, with no success. In the first MWE (note1), the result in the text is fine, and I almost get what I want in the footnote, except that the numbers in the footnote are flushed right. I tried to put them in a little box to correct this (note2), and the result is perfect in the footnote, but then the little box also appears apparently in the main text (I have exagerated the dimension in order to show clearly what happens)!

Here is the first MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[body={10cm, 3cm}]{geometry}  
\usepackage[french]{babel}  
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage[splitrule, hang]{footmisc}
\setlength{\parindentFFN}{0.2cm}
\renewcommand{\dotFFN}{}
\renewcommand{\kernFFN}{\hspace{1 cm}}

\setcounter{footnote}{8}

\begin{document}
A lot of text to place footnotes\footnote{Note 1.}. A lot of text in order to place   footnotes\footnote{Note 2.}. 
\end{document}
```

[image: First attempt]
and here is my second attempt with the MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[body={10cm, 3cm}]{geometry}  
\usepackage[french]{babel}  
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage[splitrule]{footmisc}
\setlength{\parindentFFN}{1cm}
\renewcommand{\dotFFN}{}
\renewcommand{\kernFFN}{\hspace{1 cm}}
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\hbox to 1cm{\arabic{footnote}\hss}}
\setcounter{footnote}{8}

\begin{document}
A lot of text to place footnotes\footnote{Note 1.}. A lot of text in order to place   footnotes\footnote{Note 2.}. 
\end{document}
```

and the second result.
[image: Secondattempt]

I do not find how to have the main text of my first example and the footnotes of my second. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redefine the command `\insertfootnotemarkFB` as follows:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\insertfootnotemarkFB
  {\rule\z@\footnotesep
   \makebox[\parindentFFN][l]{\@thefnmark}%
   \dotFFN
   \kernFFN
  }
\makeatother
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[body={10cm, 3cm}]{geometry}  
\usepackage[french]{babel}  
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage[splitrule]{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\dotFFN}{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\insertfootnotemarkFB
  {\rule\z@\footnotesep
   \makebox[\parindentFFN][l]{\@thefnmark}%
   \dotFFN
   \kernFFN
  }
\makeatother
\setcounter{footnote}{8}

\begin{document}
A lot of text to place footnotes\footnote{Note 1.}. A lot of text in
order to place footnotes\footnote{Note 2.}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, but when I copy your solution, I get an error message : \insertfootnotemarkFB undefined. Is it possible that on this machine the version of babel(-french) is obsolete or do I need another package  ? I do not have a complete control of the version unfortunately.

Comment: Then you probably have an old version of `babel.sty` and `french.ldf` installed. The current versions are `babel 2016/04/23 3.9r` and `frenchb 2016/05/14 v3.2c`. What does your log file say?

Comment: Try `\renewcommand\@makefntext` instead of `\renewcommand\insertfootnotemarkFB`. If this doesn't help, try moving the code (including `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`) after `\begin{document}`. It might be easier to devise a working solution if you can specify the version number of `babel.sty` and `french.ldf`.

Comment: I have babel<3.9l> (2015/01/01). Interestingly enough, as I just checked, I have the latest possible version of TeXshop (which is how my current Babel was installed)...Thanks again.

Comment: If updating `babel` and `frenchb` fails, download [frenchb.dtx](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/french/frenchb.dtx) and [frenchb.ins](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/french/frenchb.ins) and run latex on `frenchb.ins`. This will generate a file `frenchb.ldf`; move it into the same directory as your document. And then keep the fingers crossed that it doesn't need the newest version of `babel`, otherwise you would have to download a new version as well.

Comment: The \@makefntext also is refused and moving the code generated the same problem.   I shall try the updating tricks you suggest (or/and arrange to have the latest version installed next Monday !). Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution, patching `\insertfootnotemarkFB` with the help of `xpatch`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright,french]{book}
\usepackage[body={10cm, 3cm}, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[splitrule, hang]{footmisc}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\insertfootnotemarkFB}{\llap}{\hbox to \FBfnindent}{}{}
\setlength{\parindentFFN}{0cm}
\renewcommand{\dotFFN}{}
\renewcommand{\kernFFN}{\kern 0.65em}
\setcounter{footnote}{8}

\begin{document}

A lot of text to place footnotes\footnote{Note 1.}. A lot of text in order to place footnotes\footnote{Note 2.}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I had the same problem as above (unrecognized command) but wit the last version of TeXlive 2016 (babel 3.9r etc), both solutions work perfectly.